# Why verbally hurting one's wife is found in Choshen Mishpat?

Tags: halacha, women, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

> צריך ליזהר באונאת אשתו לפי שדמעתה מצויה:‏
>   ([C"M 228](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.228.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en))

I understand that the whole chapter is about fraud (הונאה) and לשון נופלת על לשון, but the question is:

Does the fact that haMechaber listed this Halachah here between monetary laws imply that it can be claimed in court and be payable?

Comment: Why not ask about אונאת דברים in general? There’s no payment for any such case; why is it included in CM at all, rather than YD?

Comment: Can you support your implied claim that that line refers to verbal abuse rather than financial?

Comment: @msh210 Good point, isn't it "הונאת דברים"?